# Always declare std::mutex as mutable in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, constants, mutable

After watching Herb Sutter's talk [You Don't Know const and mutable](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/12/you-dont-know-const-and-mutable-herb-sutter), I wonder whether I should always define a mutex as mutable? If yes, I guess the same holds for any synchronized container (e.g., `tbb::concurrent_queue`)?

Some background: In his talk, he stated that const == mutable == thread-safe, and `std::mutex` is per definition thread-safe.

There is also related question about the talk, [Does const mean thread-safe in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127379/does-const-mean-thread-safe-in-c11).

Edit:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127333/should-mutexes-be-mutable?rq=1), I found a related question (possibly a duplicate). It was asked before C++11, though. Maybe that makes a difference.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No. However, most of the time they will be.

While it's helpful to think of `const` as "thread-safe" and `mutable` as "(already) thread-safe", `const` is still fundamentally tied to the notion of promising "I won't change this value". It always will be.

I have a long-ish train of thought so bear with me.

In my own programming, I put `const` everywhere. If I have a value, it's a bad thing to change it unless I say I want to. If you try to purposefully modify a const-object, you get a compile-time error (easy to fix and no shippable result!). If you accidentally modify a non-const object, you get a runtime programming error, a bug in a compiled application, and a headache. So it's better to err on the former side and keep things `const`.

For example:

```
bool is_even(const unsigned x)
{
    return (x % 2) == 0;
}

bool is_prime(const unsigned x)
{
    return /* left as an exercise for the reader */;
} 

template <typename Iterator>
void print_special_numbers(const Iterator first, const Iterator last)
{
    for (auto iter = first; iter != last; ++iter)
    {
        const auto& x = *iter;
        const bool isEven = is_even(x);
        const bool isPrime = is_prime(x);

        if (isEven && isPrime)
            std::cout << "Special number! " << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Why are the parameter types for `is_even` and `is_prime` marked `const`? Because from an implementation point of view, changing the number I'm testing would be an error! Why `const auto& x`? Because I don't intend on changing that value, and I want the compiler to yell at me if I do. Same with `isEven` and `isPrime`: the result of this test should not change, so enforce it.

Of course `const` member functions are merely a way to give `this` a type of the form `const T*`. It says "it would be an error in implementation if I were to change some of my members".

`mutable` says "except me". This is where the "old" notion of "logically const" comes from. Consider the common use-case he gave: a mutex member. You *need* to lock this mutex to ensure your program is correct, so you need to modify it. You don't want the function to be non-const, though, because it would be an error to modify any other member. So you make it `const` and mark the mutex as `mutable`.

*None of this has to do with thread-safety.*

I think it's one step too far to say the new definitions replace the old ideas given above; they merely complement it from another view, that of thread-safety.

Now the point of view Herb gives that if you have `const` functions, they need to be thread-safe to be safely usable by the standard library. As a corollary of this, the only members you should really mark as `mutable` are those that are already thread-safe, because they are modifiable from a `const` function:

```
struct foo
{
    void act() const
    {
        mNotThreadSafe = "oh crap! const meant I would be thread-safe!";
    }

    mutable std::string mNotThreadSafe;
};
```

Okay, so we know that thread-safe things *can* be marked as `mutable`, you ask: should they be?

I think we have to consider both view simultaneously. From Herb's new point of view, yes. They are thread safe so do not need to be bound by the const-ness of the function. But just because they *can* safely be excused from the constraints of `const` doesn't mean they have to be. I still need to consider: would it be an error in implementation if I did modify that member? If so, it needs to not be `mutable`!

There's a granularity issue here: some functions may need to modify the would-be `mutable` member while others don't. This is like wanting only some functions to have friend-like access, but we can only friend the entire class. (It's a language design issue.)

In this case, you should err on the side of `mutable`.

Herb spoke just slightly too loosely when he gave a `const_cast` example an declared it safe. Consider:

```
struct foo
{
    void act() const
    {
        const_cast<unsigned&>(counter)++;
    }

    unsigned counter;
};
```

This is safe under most circumstances, except when the `foo` object itself is `const`:

```
foo x;
x.act(); // okay

const foo y;
y.act(); // UB!
```

This is covered elsewhere on SO, but `const foo`, implies the `counter` member is also `const`, and modifying a `const` object is undefined behavior.

This is why you should err on the side of `mutable`: `const_cast` does not quite give you the same guarantees. Had `counter` been marked `mutable`, it wouldn't have been a `const` object.

Okay, so if we need it `mutable` in one spot we need it everywhere, and we just need to be careful in the cases where we don't. Surely this means all thread-safe members should be marked `mutable` then?

Well no, because not all thread-safe members are there for internal synchronization. The most trivial example is some sort of wrapper class (not always best practice but they exist):

```
struct threadsafe_container_wrapper
{
    void missing_function_I_really_want()
    {
        container.do_this();
        container.do_that();
    }

    const_container_view other_missing_function_I_really_want() const
    {
        return container.const_view();
    }

    threadsafe_container container;
};
```

Here we are wrapping `threadsafe_container` and providing another member function we want (would be better as a free function in practice). No need for `mutable` here, the correctness from the old point of view utterly trumps: in one function I'm modifying the container *and that's okay because I didn't say I wouldn't* (omitting `const`), and in the other I'm not modifying the container *and ensure I'm keeping that promise* (omitting `mutable`).

I think Herb is arguing the most cases where we'd use `mutable` we're also using some sort of internal (thread-safe) synchronization object, and I agree. Ergo his point of view works most of the time. But there exist cases where I simply *happen* to have a thread-safe object and merely treat it as yet another member; in this case we fall back on the old and fundamental use of `const`.

Comment: +1, but I think one key phrase that is missing is that constness relates to a method's _observable_ behavior, not necessarily logical behavior.

Answer (score 11):

I just watched the talk, and I do not entirely agree with what Herb Sutter is saying.

If I understand correctly, his argument is as follows:

1. `[res.on.data.races]/3` imposes a requirement on types that are used with the standard library -- non-const member functions must be thread-safe.
2. Therefore `const` is equivalent to thread-safe.
3. And if `const` is equivalent to thread-safe, the `mutable` must be equivalent to "trust me, even the non-const members of this variable are thread-safe".

In my opinion, all three parts of this argument are flawed (and the second part is critically flawed).

The problem with `1` is that `[res.on.data.races]` gives requirements for types in the standard library, not types to be used with the standard library. That said, I think it is reasonable (but not entirely clear-cut) to interpret `[res.on.data.races]` as also giving requirements for types to be used with the standard library, because it would be practically impossible for a library implementation to uphold the requirement to not modify objects through `const` references if `const` member functions were able to modify objects.

The *critical* problem with `2` is that while it is true (if we accept `1`) that `const` must imply thread-safe, it is **not** true that thread-safe implies `const`, and so the two are not equivalent. `const` still implies "logically immutable", it is just that the scope for "logically immutability" has expanded to require thread-safety.

If we take `const` and thread-safe to be equivalent, we lose the nice feature of `const` which is that it allows us to easily reason about code by seeing where values can be modified:

```
//`a` is `const` because `const` and thread-safe are equivalent.
//Does this function modify a?
void foo(std::atomic<int> const& a);
```

Furthermore, the relevant section of `[res.on.data.races]` talks about "modifies", which can be reasonably interpreted in the more general sense of "changes in an externally observable way", rather than just "changes in a thread-unsafe way".

The problem with `3` is simply that it can only be true if `2` is true, and `2` is critically flawed.

---

So to apply this to your question -- no, you should not make every internally synchronised object `mutable`.

#### In C++11, as in C++03, `const` means "logically immutable" and `mutable` means "can change, but the change will not be externally observable". The only difference is that in C++11, "logically immutable" has been expanded to include "thread-safe".

You should reserve `mutable` for member variables that do not affect the externally visible state of the object. On the other hand (and this is the key point that Herb Sutter makes in his talk), if you have a member that *is* mutable for some reason, that member *must* be internally synchronised, otherwise you risk making `const` not imply thread-safe, and this would cause undefined behaviour with the standard library.

Comment: 'In C++11, as in C++03, `const` means "logically immutable" and `mutable` means "can change, but the change will not be externally observable". The only difference is that in C++11, "logically immutable" has been expanded to include "thread-safe".'

This is what Herb was saying.

Comment: @Miles Rout: Maybe it is what he meant to say, but it is not what he actually said. In his talk, he very explicitly says "const == threadsafe". "const implies threadsafe" is not the same as "const is equivalent to threadsafe". One is a one-way implication, the other is a two-way implication. The two-way implication that is given in the talk is not valid, since there are thread-safe operations that do modify objects; and using `const` for those would make `const` less useful.

Comment: `==` doesn't mean "is equivalent to"

Answer (score 6):

Let's talk about the change in `const`.

```
void somefunc(Foo&);
void somefunc(const Foo&);
```

In C++03 and before, the `const` version, compared to the non-`const` one, provides additional guarantees to the callers. It promises not to modify its argument, where by modification we mean calling `Foo`'s non-const member functions (including assignment etc), or passing it to functions that expect a non-`const` argument, or doing same to its exposed non-mutable data members. `somefunc` restricts itself to `const` operations on `Foo`. And the additional guarantee is totally one-sided. Neither the caller nor the `Foo` provider do not have to do anything special in order to call the `const` version. Anyone who is able to call the non-`const` version can call the `const` version too.

In C++11 this changes. The `const` version still provides the same guarantee to the caller, but now it comes with a price. *The provider of `Foo` must make sure that all `const` operations are thread safe*. Or it least it must do so when `somefunc` is a standard library function. Why? Because the standard library *may* parallelize its operations, and it *will* call `const` operations on anything and everything without any additional synchronization. So you, the user, must make sure this additional synchronization is not needed. Of course this is not a problem in most cases, as most classes have no mutable members and most `const` operations don't touch global data.

So what `mutable` means now? It's the same as before! Namely, this data is non-const, but it is an implementation detail, I promise it does not affect the observable behavior. This means that no, you don't have to mark everything in sight `mutable`, just as you didn't do it in C++98. So when you should mark a data member `mutable`? Just like in C++98, when you need to call its non-`const` operations from a `const` method, and you can guarantee it won't break anything. To reiterate:

- if your data member's physical state does not affect the observable state of the object
- *and* it is thread-safe (internally synchronized)
- then you can (if you need to!) go ahead and declare it `mutable`.

The first condition is imposed, like in C++98, because other code, including the standard library, may call your `const` methods and nobody should observe any changes resulting from such calls. The second condition is there, and this is what's new in C++11, because such calls can be made asynchronously.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer covers the question, but it's worth mentioning that Sutter has since changed the slide that incorrectly suggested that const == mutable == thread-safe. The blog post that lead to that slide change can be found here:

[What Sutter got wrong about Const in C++11](http://codecraft.co/2013/01/02/how-sutters-wrong-about-const-in-cpp-11/)

TL:DR Const and Mutable both imply Thread-safe, but have different meanings in regards to what can and can't be changed in your program.