# Async TCP server to receive audio chunks get Access Violation errors

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, mutex, sfml

I started a voice chat server project, using boost::asio and SMFL audio library. I think my mutex logic is not correct, because I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00B7871D in TCPAudioReceiver.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

The debugger stops at the `if(mServer.samplesAvailable())` line in the main and I also notice that the `if(mSamplesQueue.front().size() > 256) return true;` line in the server reads a size of `{???}`. I thought that locking the server's mutex would be enough to protect against this kind of problem, but I think I'm still one or two concepts away from the good design.

I used recursive_mutex for no particular reason a this point, it was more an attempt of getting farther in my troubleshooting.

How would you suggest I solve this problem?

main

```
#include "TcpAsyncServer.h"
#include "TcpAsyncSession.h"
#include "AudioStream.h"
#include <thread>

int main()
{
  io_service ioService;
  deque<vector<Int16>> mSamplesQueue;
  SoundBuffer mSoundBuffer;
  AudioStream mAudioStream;

  cout << "Starting server..." << endl;
  Server mServer(ioService, PORT);
  thread serviceThread([&](){ioService.run();}); 

  cout << "Starting reception loop..." << endl;
  for(;;) { 
    {
      lock_guard<recursive_mutex> lock(mServer.mServerMutex);
      // Look for new samples
      if(mServer.samplesAvailable()) {            // <-- debugger stops here
        cout << "Samples available..." << endl;
        vector<Int16> wSamples;
        mServer.getNextSamples(wSamples);
        mSamplesQueue.push_back(wSamples);
      }
    }

    // Loading and playing samples
    if((mAudioStream.getStatus() != AudioStream::Playing) && !mSamplesQueue.empty()) {
      cout << "Loading and playing audio stream..." << endl;
      if(mSoundBuffer.loadFromSamples(
        reinterpret_cast<Int16*>(mSamplesQueue.front().data()), 
        mSamplesQueue.front().size(), 2, 48000)
      )
      {
        cout << "SoundBuffer loaded successfully..." << endl;
        mAudioStream.load(mSoundBuffer);
        mAudioStream.play();
        mSamplesQueue.pop_front();
      }
      else cout << "SoundBuffer failed to load..." << endl;
    }

    // Give it some room to play the sound
    while (mAudioStream.getStatus() == AudioStream::Playing) {
      sleep(milliseconds(50));
    }
  }
  serviceThread.join();
}
```

Server header

```
#include <mutex>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

using namespace sf;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using namespace std;

#define PORT 2112
#define SAMPLE_BUFFER 512

class Server
{

public:
  // Ctor
  Server(io_service & iService, short iPort);

  // Methods
  bool samplesAvailable();
  void getNextSamples(vector<Int16> oSamples);
  void pushSamples(vector<Int16> iSamples);

  // Variables
  recursive_mutex mServerMutex;

private:

  // Methods
  void doAccept();

  // Variables
  tcp::acceptor mAcceptor;
  tcp::socket   mSocket;
  deque<vector<Int16>> mSamplesQueue;
};
```

Server class

```
#include "TcpAsyncServer.h"
#include "TcpAsyncSession.h"

Server::Server(io_service & service, short port)
  : mAcceptor(service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
    mSocket(service) {
  doAccept();
}

void Server::doAccept()
{
  mAcceptor.async_accept(mSocket,
    [this]
    (boost::system::error_code error) {
      if(!error) make_shared<Session>(move(mSocket),this)->start();
      doAccept();
    }
  );
}

bool Server::samplesAvailable() {
  lock_guard<recursive_mutex> lock(mServerMutex);
  if(mSamplesQueue.front().size() > 256) return true; // <-- mSamplesQueue.front() has undefined size
  return false;
}

void Server::getNextSamples(vector<Int16> oSamples) {
  lock_guard<recursive_mutex> lock(mServerMutex);
  oSamples = mSamplesQueue.front();   
  mSamplesQueue.pop_front();
}

void Server::pushSamples(vector<Int16> iSamples) {
  lock_guard<recursive_mutex> lock(mServerMutex);
  mSamplesQueue.push_back(iSamples);
}
```

Session header

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

class Server;

class Session : public enable_shared_from_this<Session>
{

public:
  // Ctor
  Session(tcp::socket & iSocket, Server* iServerPtr);

  // Methods
  void start();

private:
  // Methods
  void doRead();

  // Variables
  tcp::socket   mSocket;
  char          mData[BUFFER_SIZE];
  Server*       mServerPtr; 
  deque<vector<Int16>> mSampleBufferQueue;
};
```

Session class

```
#include "TcpAsyncSession.h"
#include "TcpAsyncServer.h"

Session::Session(tcp::socket & iSocket, Server* iServerPtr)
  : mSocket(move(iSocket)),
    mServerPtr(iServerPtr) 
{}

void Session::start() {
  doRead();
}

void Session::doRead() {
  shared_ptr<Session> self(shared_from_this());

  mSocket.async_read_some(buffer(mData,BUFFER_SIZE),
    [this,self]
    (boost::system::error_code error, size_t iBytesReceived) {
      if(!error) {
        cout << "Receiving " << iBytesReceived << " bytes..." << endl; 
        vector<Int16> wSamples;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < iBytesReceived; i+=2) {
          wSamples.push_back(static_cast<Int16>( mData[i]<<8 | mData[i] ));
        }

        {
          lock_guard<recursive_mutex> lock(mServerPtr->mServerMutex);
          mServerPtr->pushSamples(move(wSamples));
        }

        doRead();
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Voting to close, because there's way too much code. Anyhow, one advise: Document which data are shared and which mutex must be locked to access those data. Then, audit your code that this rule is not broken anywhere.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Different standards :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow that's lengthy.

Your most conspicuous error is here:

```
if (mSamplesQueue.front().size() > 256)
    return true; // <-- mSamplesQueue.front() has undefined size
```

You should check that `mSamplesQueue.empty()` is not true, otherwise using `front()` is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead of

```
bool Server::samplesAvailable() {
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mServerMutex);

    if (mSamplesQueue.front().size() > 256)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

You could simply write

```
bool Server::samplesAvailable() {
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mServerMutex);
    return mSamplesQueue.size() && mSamplesQueue.front().size()>256;
}
```

---

Reviewing:

- there's UB in

  ```
  wSamples.push_back(static_cast<Int16>(mData[i] << 8 | mData[i]));
  ```

  you needed parentheses, and on many compilers `char` is signed,which leads to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) with left-shift.
- never use `using`-directives in header files. **Especially** not `using namespace std;` ([Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))
- there's a quite bit of unnecessary buffer copying, why not just reinterpret cast the `char[]` buffer on platforms with the appropriate endianness, and/or why not `std::move` in `pushSamples()`:

  ```
  mSamplesQueue.push_back(std::move(iSamples));
  ```
- using class members directly is a code smell ([Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)). In particular, it's a sure sign you're mixing levels of abstraction when you write:

  ```
  {
      std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mServerPtr->mServerMutex);
      mServerPtr->pushSamples(std::move(wSamples));
  }
  ```

  Especially since you already have

  ```
  void Server::pushSamples(std::vector<sf::Int16> iSamples) {
      std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mServerMutex);
      mSamplesQueue.push_back(std::move(iSamples));
  }
  ```

  This means that at this time you **require** a recursive mutex, because otherwise you'd have a deadlock.
- `Session::mSampleBufferQueue` is unused
- The signature of `getNextSamples` is wrong. You will never see any effect because the parameter is passed by value. Either declare it:

  ```
  void getNextSamples(std::vector<sf::Int16>& oSamples);
  ```

  or

  ```
  std::vector<sf::Int16> getNextSamples();
  ```
- consider making methods like `samplesAvailable()` const. To do this, you'll need to mark the mutex `mutable` ([Always declare std::mutex as mutable in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131572/always-declare-stdmutex-as-mutable-in-c11))

### Conceptual Problems

Conceptually, there's a problem with the accepting of concurrent clients. You will end up playing streams randomly interleaved if that actually happens.

### Fixed Up Version

- main.cpp

  ```
  //#include "AudioStream.h"
  #include "TcpAsyncServer.h"
  #include "TcpAsyncSession.h"
  #include <thread>

  struct AudioStream {
      enum Status { Playing, Buffering };
      Status getStatus() const { return Buffering; }
      void load(sf::SoundBuffer const& buf) {
          // 
          std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ 
              << " rate=" << buf.getSampleRate() 
              << " channels=" << buf.getChannelCount() 
              << " duration=" << buf.getDuration().asSeconds() << "s "
              << " samples=" << buf.getSampleCount()
              << "\n";
      }
      void play() {}
  };

  int main() {
      boost::asio::io_service ioService;
      std::deque<std::vector<sf::Int16> > mSamplesQueue;
      sf::SoundBuffer mSoundBuffer;
      AudioStream mAudioStream;

      std::cout << "Starting server..." << std::endl;
      Server mServer(ioService, PORT); // start async accept loop
      std::thread serviceThread([&]() { ioService.run(); });

      std::cout << "Starting reception loop..." << std::endl;
      for (;;) {
          {
              std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mServer.mServerMutex);

              // Look for new samples
              if (mServer.samplesAvailable()) {
                  std::cout << "Samples available..." << std::endl;
                  std::vector<sf::Int16> wSamples;
                  mServer.getNextSamples(wSamples);
                  mSamplesQueue.push_back(wSamples);
              }
          }

          // Loading and playing samples
          if ((mAudioStream.getStatus() != AudioStream::Playing) && !mSamplesQueue.empty()) {
              std::cout << "Loading and playing audio stream..." << std::endl;
              if (mSoundBuffer.loadFromSamples(reinterpret_cast<sf::Int16 *>(mSamplesQueue.front().data()),
                                               mSamplesQueue.front().size(), 2, 48000)) {
                  std::cout << "SoundBuffer loaded successfully..." << std::endl;
                  mAudioStream.load(mSoundBuffer);
                  mAudioStream.play();
                  mSamplesQueue.pop_front();
              } else
                  std::cout << "SoundBuffer failed to load..." << std::endl;
          }

          // Give it some room to play the sound
          while (mAudioStream.getStatus() == AudioStream::Playing) {
              sleep(sf::milliseconds(50));
          }
      }
      serviceThread.join();
  }
  ```
- TcpAsyncServer.h

  ```
  #include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
  #include <boost/asio.hpp>
  #include <deque>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <mutex>
  #include <vector>

  #define PORT 2113
  #define SAMPLE_BUFFER 5120000

  class Server {
      using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

    public:
      // Ctor
      Server(boost::asio::io_service &iService, short iPort);

      // Methods
      bool samplesAvailable() const;
      void getNextSamples(std::vector<sf::Int16>& oSamples);
      void pushSamples(std::vector<sf::Int16> iSamples);

      // Variables
      mutable std::recursive_mutex mServerMutex;

    private:
      // Methods
      void doAccept();

      // Variables
      tcp::acceptor mAcceptor;
      tcp::socket mSocket;
      std::deque<std::vector<sf::Int16> > mSamplesQueue;
  };
  ```
- TcpAsyncSession.h

  ```
  #include <boost/asio.hpp>

  #define BUFFER_SIZE 10240000

  class Server;

  class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
      using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

    public:
      // Ctor
      Session(tcp::socket &&iSocket, Server *iServerPtr);

      // Methods
      void start();

    private:
      // Methods
      void doRead();

      // Variables
      tcp::socket mSocket;
      uint8_t mData[BUFFER_SIZE];
      Server *mServerPtr;
  };
  ```
- TcpAsyncServer.cpp

  ```
  #include "TcpAsyncServer.h"
  #include "TcpAsyncSession.h"

  Server::Server(boost::asio::io_service &service, short port) : mAcceptor(service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)), mSocket(service) {
      mAcceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address());
      doAccept();
  }

  void Server::doAccept() {
      mAcceptor.async_accept(mSocket, [this](boost::system::error_code error) {
          if (!error)
              std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(mSocket), this)->start();
          doAccept();
      });
  }

  bool Server::samplesAvailable() const {
      std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mServerMutex);
      return mSamplesQueue.size() && mSamplesQueue.front().size()>256;
  }

  void Server::getNextSamples(std::vector<sf::Int16>& oSamples) {
      std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mServerMutex);
      oSamples = std::move(mSamplesQueue.front());
      mSamplesQueue.pop_front();
  }

  void Server::pushSamples(std::vector<sf::Int16> iSamples) {
      std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mServerMutex);
      mSamplesQueue.push_back(std::move(iSamples));
  }
  ```
- TcpAsyncSession.cpp

  ```
  #include "TcpAsyncServer.h"
  #include "TcpAsyncSession.h"

  //#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
  #include <iostream>

  Session::Session(tcp::socket &&iSocket, Server *iServerPtr) : mSocket(std::move(iSocket)), mServerPtr(iServerPtr) {}

  void Session::start() { doRead(); }

  void Session::doRead() {

      std::shared_ptr<Session> self(shared_from_this());

      mSocket.async_read_some(
              boost::asio::buffer(mData, BUFFER_SIZE),
              [this, self](boost::system::error_code error, size_t iBytesReceived) {
                  if (error)
                      return;
                  std::cout << "Receiving " << iBytesReceived << " bytes..." << std::endl;
                  std::vector<sf::Int16> wSamples;

                  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < iBytesReceived; i += 2) {
                      wSamples.push_back(static_cast<sf::Int16>((mData[i] << 8) | mData[i]));
                  }

                  mServerPtr->pushSamples(std::move(wSamples));

                  doRead();
          });
  }
  ```

### Demo Run

Feeding it a 138M mp3:

```
Starting server...
Starting reception loop...
Receiving 8192 bytes...
Samples available...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=0.042666s  samples=4096
Receiving 562829 bytes...
Samples available...
Receiving 745525 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
An internal OpenAL call failed in SoundBuffer.cpp(265).
Expression:
   alBufferData(m_buffer, format, &m_samples[0], size, sampleRate)
Error description:
   AL_INVALID_VALUE
   A numeric argument is out of range.

SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=2.93141s  samples=281415
Samples available...
Loading and playing audio stream...
Receiving 2815769 bytes...
An internal OpenAL call failed in SoundBuffer.cpp(265).
Expression:
   alBufferData(m_buffer, format, &m_samples[0], size, sampleRate)
Error description:
   AL_INVALID_VALUE
   A numeric argument is out of range.

SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=3.88295s  samples=372763
Samples available...
Receiving 4978211 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
An internal OpenAL call failed in SoundBuffer.cpp(265).
Expression:
   alBufferData(m_buffer, format, &m_samples[0], size, sampleRate)
Error description:
   AL_INVALID_VALUE
   A numeric argument is out of range.

SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=14.6655s  samples=1407885
Samples available...
Receiving 5632954 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=25.9282s  samples=2489106
Samples available...
Receiving 5893470 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
An internal OpenAL call failed in SoundBuffer.cpp(265).
Expression:
   alBufferData(m_buffer, format, &m_samples[0], size, sampleRate)
Error description:
   AL_INVALID_VALUE
   A numeric argument is out of range.

SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=29.3383s  samples=2816477
Samples available...
Receiving 5895401 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
An internal OpenAL call failed in SoundBuffer.cpp(265).
Expression:
   alBufferData(m_buffer, format, &m_samples[0], size, sampleRate)
Error description:
   AL_INVALID_VALUE
   A numeric argument is out of range.

SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=30.6952s  samples=2946735
Samples available...
Receiving 5894091 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
An internal OpenAL call failed in SoundBuffer.cpp(265).
Expression:
   alBufferData(m_buffer, format, &m_samples[0], size, sampleRate)
Error description:
   AL_INVALID_VALUE
   A numeric argument is out of range.

SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=30.7052s  samples=2947701
Samples available...
Receiving 5894197 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=30.6984s  samples=2947046
Samples available...
Receiving 5894303 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
An internal OpenAL call failed in SoundBuffer.cpp(265).
Expression:
   alBufferData(m_buffer, format, &m_samples[0], size, sampleRate)
Error description:
   AL_INVALID_VALUE
   A numeric argument is out of range.

SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=30.6989s  samples=2947099
Samples available...
Receiving 5894144 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=30.6995s  samples=2947152
Samples available...
Receiving 5896192 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=30.6987s  samples=2947072
Samples available...
Receiving 5961675 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=30.7093s  samples=2948096
Samples available...
Receiving 5961728 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0504s  samples=2980838
Samples available...
Receiving 5960615 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0507s  samples=2980864
Samples available...
Receiving 5960793 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0449s  samples=2980308
Samples available...
Receiving 5960668 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
An internal OpenAL call failed in SoundBuffer.cpp(265).
Expression:
   alBufferData(m_buffer, format, &m_samples[0], size, sampleRate)
Error description:
   AL_INVALID_VALUE
   A numeric argument is out of range.

SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0458s  samples=2980397
Samples available...
Receiving 5960740 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0451s  samples=2980334
Samples available...
Receiving 5960668 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0455s  samples=2980370
Samples available...
Receiving 5960740 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0451s  samples=2980334
Samples available...
Receiving 5960668 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0455s  samples=2980370
Samples available...
Receiving 5960740 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0451s  samples=2980334
Samples available...
Receiving 5960668 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0455s  samples=2980370
Samples available...
Receiving 5960740 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0451s  samples=2980334
Samples available...
Receiving 5960668 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0455s  samples=2980370
Samples available...
Receiving 5960740 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0451s  samples=2980334
Samples available...
Receiving 4770135 bytes...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
void AudioStream::load(const sf::SoundBuffer &) rate=48000 channels=2 duration=31.0455s  samples=2980370
Samples available...
Loading and playing audio stream...
SoundBuffer loaded successfully...
```

Apart from the fact that my mock `AudioStream` doesn't initialize the audio-library properly, that looks fine to me.

Note that I increased the buffer sizes a lot so the log would not be too large.

Comment: [Added](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49018787/revisions) one more review hint about const-correctness.