# Is using mutable for class mutex so that methods can be declared const good design?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to  know is this a good design if I need multithread safe class.

1) Design methods as a normal non thread safe class would have them, taking care to tag methods with const if they dont modify members. Ofc take this with a grain of salt, for example concurant vector cant have pop_back(), only try_pop() ...

2) Add mutable mutex to the class and lock it using lock_guard every at begining every method(taking care not to do double lock on mutex if it is nonrecursive)

Example:

```
size_t MyClass::getSize() const
{
  lock_guard<mutex> lg(mtx); //mtx is mutable
  return cont.size();

}
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127333/should-mutexes-be-mutable

Comment: I think that it somewhat depends on your "programming religion" about constness

Comment: @ForEveR voting to close as duplicate. :)

Comment: More info about this on Herb's [You don't know const and mutable](http://herbsutter.com/2013/01/01/video-you-dont-know-const-and-mutable/) talk.